# Netflix desktop and Wine

Tags: wine, netflix

Is there a way to reliably install Netflix desktop and the full version of Wine? I want to be able to use Netflix, but also have a full-functioning wine install.

How would be the best way to do this? Thanks!

edit: It seems that they are actually fully compatible now. I posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like Netflix-Desktop and Wine actually naturally coexist. I don't think this used to be the case, but I believe the programmer made it so Netflix-Desktop is based off of a patched version of wine with a different name/folder system. Anyhow, they both run well, without conflicting with eachother.

For anyone interested in the Netflix-Desktop, here's the link:
http://www.compholio.com/netflix-desktop/